# Unity: Edge of quad is dark. How do I avoid this?

Tags: unity

I have four quads together like this

[image]

These are just the default Unity quad from create\3d object\quad

the texture is white with grey borders on two sides and a black border on other two sides..

Lets zoom in..
[image]

How do I get rid of these black lines?

I am generating these bigger shapes out of quads and applying the texture using code... 
I noticed that If I didnt change the material in code then there were no black lines.
So I made prefabs for each material, and am now spawning those in instead of changing a material on a quad. But I still get the same lines.
Also, if I drag the prefabs into the scene when the game is running they appear perfect.
I have no idea whats going on.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok I changed the texture wrap mode to clamp (it was repeat by default) and that fixed the black lines...

At the edges it was fading into the color at the opposite edge.